# Replacement Rim Suggestions!

Tags: rims, replacement

I need to replace a rim that is cracked around the spokes.  This is my bike: http://www.bikes.com/en/bikes/whistler/2015 (Whistler 70)

I can't find any info on my current clincher rim (700C) for my 32mm tires.  I'm looking to replace it with a rim that is "fast" on pavement and can handle well on dirt and gravel trails.  I don't know much about rim profiles or rim technology, etc, so I'm looking for some suggestions on manufacturers of rims that perform well and aren't too costly.  Also, any links to info on how to choose a rim would be helpful too!  Thanks!

Comment: You have asked about replacing you rim previously. Be aware that directly asking asking for product recommendations is off-topic on this site.

Comment: Per [your own link](https://www.bikes.com/en/bikes/whistler/2015): "**Rims** Wheeltech TD26 by Alex Rims"  Find the [ERD](https://www.google.com/search?q=effective+rim+diameter), count the holes, and get a replacement.